# facebook PermissionDialog

Tags: facebook

```
 <script
 src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 FB.init('cef61789d5df166ac00c9fe13007c110', "xd_receiver.htm");
 FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("offline_access");
 </script>
```

After a user login i am using the above code to get the Dialog box.

Why itsnt showing permission dialog??

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  Wrap the call to FB.Connect inside an "ensure init" like so:

`FB.ensureInit(function() { FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("offline_access"); });`

That cleared things up for me.